# parsing string response http

Tags: php, json, http

I'm going to give a basic example of what I need to be able to do, in the hopes that somebody can point me in the right direction

I prepare the URL required for the HTTP GET request to get data (trains between destinations by simply typing the name of the stations) from oncf.ma

I used cURL for that purpose but the response is string. here is the code i used,

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'www.oncf.ma/Pages/ResultatsHoraire.aspx?depart=BERRECHID&arrivee=BENGUERIR&CodeRD=0093&CodeGD=00183&CodeRA=0093&CodeGA=00120&heure=0000&date=19/11/2013');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
```

What I need to do, that I don't know how to do, is how can manipulate string to get just data needs and not all html parsing to string.

response is change if we change parameters.

Comment: Your first step is to figure out how the auto-generated page implements consistent element structures. The class `s4-wpcell-plain` is implemented 3 times on every page regardless of the parameters, and the third implementation contains the train schedule data. I would start there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the result is HTML.  In that case, you'll want to create a DOMDocument (see https://www.php.net/book.dom for all of the PHP documentation on that topic) and process it that way.

Your first step will look like this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHtml( $content );
```

Now, you can manipulate "$document" using its member functions.  For example, to get all of the "td" instances, you could call:

```
$elements = $document->getElementsByTagName( "td" );
```

(See https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php for more information on that function.)

Comment: I have Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag ie:menuitem invalid in Entity

Comment: DOMDocument will print warnings when there's "imperfect" HTML; as long as you can get to the the stuff that you want, it's no big deal.  Typos happen, and some sites are just poorly formatted.  To make the warnings "go away", simply put "@" before the function call.  For example, "@$document->loadHtml( $content )"

Comment: thanks worked like charme

Comment: can you tel me how can manipluate $element to get all node

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)** for that purpose. Here are some nice getting-started guides for regex under php.

- [Regular Expressions for dummies](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/regular-expressions-for-dummies-screencast-series/)
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/01/essential-guide-to-regular-expressions-tools-tutorials-and-resources/

You can also use a DOM Parser like [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) which imitates the behaviour of *jQuery* by letting you query the DOM using *css selectors*

Comment: HTML is not regular language and it's not jQuery behavior (per se), those are CSS selectors and Sizzle.js.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to query the DOM and extract the data you want to process. See "[php xpath table parsing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607928/php-xpath-table-parsing-question)" for an example.